# Is an auth session stored in cookie safe in production? Compared to redis storage?

Tags: authentication, oauth, next-auth, clerk

I understand that redis storage + session cookie with the sessionId is safest. I coded it up and set it up using Upstash Redis but I realize if I'm checking against the redis storage every time a user requests anything, even though upstash redis is cheap, the bill will go up so quickly. Essentially, this is safest, but I'm a cheapscape and this will be expensive down the line.

So then I'm thinking of storing the session data via a cookie instead - colloquially known as JWT method (even though both use JWTs) without a redis session store. But I understand there are security concerns with this like not being able to revoke a user session.

Are sessions stored in JWT without a redis store actually used in serious production apps? JWT without redis store doesn't pass SOC2 Compliance right?

Just trying to balance my cheapness vs what is required. Or maybe authentication services are cheaper than implementing a redis store yourself nowdays frankly - open to thoughts from others who have dove down this rabbit hole as well.